# IBM MQ SDK depending on the client

Tags: ibm-mq

My understanding is that if I am using in my application the IBM.XMS.dll I aslo need to have installed in the application server the MQ Client to allow connections with the MQ Server.

What about the new libraries which support .NET Core amqmdnetstd.dll & amqmxmsstd.dll?. Are they independent of the MQ client?. Is it enough to have those DLLs bundled in your application, so you don't need the installation of MQ client in the application server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are working with MQ 9.1.

[Installing IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q132490_.htm) says that `amqmdnetstd.dll` is the successor of `amqmdnet.dll`, and [Using XMS with Microsoft .NET Core](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.xms.doc/xms_q132500.htm) says that `amqmxmsstd.dll` is the successor of the `IBM.XMS.*` libraries. These two articles link both to [Using the stand-alone IBM MQ .NET client](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q123550_.htm), which says that you can use only the DLL as MQ client.

So reading all this I would say that is enough to bundle the two DLLs with your application.

Comment: I have just realized that you commented "I assume you are working with MQ 9.1". Does this mean that the new standard libraries will only work with MQ 9.1 installed in the server? Would the new standard libraries work for MQ 9.0.0.1 for example?

Comment: My assumption was there because OP talked about `amqmdnetstd.dll`, which was introduced with MQ 9.1. MQ does a [very good compatibility job](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21312967), so you don't have to worry: "WebSphere MQ V7.0, V7.1, V7.5, V8.0, V9.0 and V9.1 queue managers and clients inter operate with queue managers and clients from any previous level of the WebSphere MQ or IBM MQ products."